# Dropzone.js multiple file upload, get upload progress for each file

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

**Update 1**

If in Dropzone configuration uploadMultiple is set to false, then it works, because it uploads just one file at the same time. But I would like to solve the problem and upload multiple files at the same time and get the progress for each file separatly.

**My Problem**

If I drag one file after another inside the dropzone the progress is showed correctly. It changes from 0 to 100%.

If I drag multiple files into the dropzone, every progress displayed is the same. Also the bytes sent are equals.

But I need an individual progress / bytes sent for each file.

I have following **Dropzone configuration**:

```
Dropzone.options.scannedFiles = {
    url: '/',
    uploadMultiple: true,
    addRemoveLinks: false,
    previewsContainer: null,
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    previewTemplate: document.getElementById('preview-template').innerHTML,
    init: function () {
        this.on('addedfile', (file) => {
            $(file.previewElement).find("[data-dzc-id]").attr('id', uuid.v4());
        });

        this.on('uploadprogress', (file, progress, bytesSent) => {
            console.log(file);
            console.log(file.upload.progress);
            console.log(file.upload.bytesSent);

            $('#'+ $(file.previewElement).find("[data-dzc-id]").attr('id')).html(file.upload.bytesSent);
        });
    }
};
```

and following **preview-template**

```
<div style="display: none" id="preview-template">
    <div class="mdz-wrapper">
        <div class="mdz-content-wrapper">
            <div class="mdz-file-icon">
                <i class="material-icons">insert_drive_file</i>
            </div>
            <div class="mdz-file-info">
                <p data-dz-name></p>
                | <p data-dz-size></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p data-dzc-id></p>
            </div>
            <i class="material-icons" data-dz-remove>cancel</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output** for the console.log() statements, when I drop two files inside the dropzone.

There is more than just one output for one file, put I posted just one because the others are just incrementing the progress and filesize.

File 1 Object (size: 269367) | **console.log(file);** 
31.078931778452883 | **console.log(file.upload.progress);** 
1277952 | **console.log(file.upload.bytesSent);** 
[p#45a3e751-89c7-41fe-8442-bab98257c688] | **console.log($('#'+ $(file.previewElement).find("[data-dzc-id]").attr('id')))**

File 2 Object (size: 3842203) 
31.078931778452883 
1277952 
[p#3fe0357e-5fae-4f6a-aa9e-895ced0469a9]

Comment: You're missing in Preview Template`<div>
            <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
            </div>
        </div>` Its known issue with BS template there is solution's in github of this plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `uploadMultiple` option to `false`.

If it's set to `true` then all files will be sent in one request and thus you will only get one progress for all the files. To get the progress of individual files you need to set `uploadMultiple` to `false`.

You can set the `parallelUploads` value to whatever value you want.